# Setting up a custom domain and SSL

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to setup a custom domain with SSL on Microsoft Azure Mobile Services?

I know how to do it for Cloud Services and Azure Websites but not the mobile services.

I get a url like: https://xxxxx.azure-mobile.net/ but I would prefer my domain for all connections in my application. You never know when you might need to redirect, filter or move things around and updating clients would be a very large job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this feature is now available with our Mobile Apps (part of Azure App Service). Checkout:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/

Comment: How does this help with azure mobile services?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the answer is no. There is no configuration I can find to allow the input of another domain and/or SSL certificate.

Its under review, will just have to wait and see.
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services/suggestions/4433702-customized-domain-name-for-mobile-services-i-wan

I will update here if this ever changes in the future.